# Converting json String to Object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, underscore.js

I have the following text in form of var in JS which i am getting from another function.

```
    var text = '["{"a1":"zxcv","a2":"pqrs","c2":[1,2,3],"a3":{"aa3":"asdfgh","aa5":null}}","{"a1":"xyz","a2":"mno","c2":[103],"a3":{"aa8":"qwerty"}}"]';
```

I have a requirement to check the count of a1, a2, c2 and it's values and a3 and its values as well.
such as: a1: 2, a2: 2, c2: 4, a3: 3 and so on (count of child elements as well)

The crude way i could think to get my result was to 1st remove the first and last " and replace }","{ with },{
This gave me a json array of objects and using JSON.parse gave me a better structure converted then i could traverse easily on that.
I couldn't find any library or other solution as alternative to this.

```js
 var text = '["{"a1":"zxcv","a2":"pqrs","c2":[1,2,3],"a3":{"aa3":"asdfgh","aa5":null}}","{"a1":"xyz","a2":"mno","c2":[103],"a3":{"aa8":"qwerty"}}"]';

        console.log(text);

        text = text.replace(/\["{/g, "[{"); // remove first double quote
        text = text.replace(/\}"]/g, "}]"); // remove last double quote
        text = text.replace(/\}","{/g, "},{"); // replace middle quotes

        console.log(text);

        var formattedText = JSON.parse(text);

        console.log(formattedText);
```

Expected output after i get it in a object form as then i can loop over object and use counter to maintain count:

a1: 2, a2: 2, c2: 4, a3: 3

Is there any function (inbuilt or with a library) that can help me with this?

Comment: Is it possible to change the input format of the string? If you could change it to valid JSON this problem could be solved in a single method call. \/ \/ \/ what he said :)

Comment: Or you could ask the source to provide you a valid JSON string, edit: What he said ^^^

Comment: Why are you getting not-JSON that you have to manually try to mangle into JSON?

Comment: are you sure isn't it better to just fix the JSON source?

Comment: You seem to have fixed the invalid JSON, which constitutes 90% of your question - so what have you tried to solve your actual issue?

Comment: RoryMcCrossan, freedomn-m actually the text here is coming directly from aws datalake and i can't change it as this is one example of row data which i have to change, other data doesn't require and change and are in different format

Comment: freedomn-m my issue was only till getting text converted in object format so that i can use it properly, i'm asking any other way to do that with any inbuilt library or function

Comment: I'm not aware of any library that takes invalid JSON and magically formats it into valid. The whole idea of having JSON as a standard is to not have to do that.

Comment: So let's summarise: you have a badly formatted JSON (ok, move on) - you can convert this to a valid JSON and then you want to...convert it to a valid JSON some *other* way, specifically via a library?  2 things: 1st as your "JSON" isn't standard, there's no way to know what random changes it has, so there won't be a library that covers these random changes - 2nd asking for a library is off topic at SO

Comment: You might like to edit your question to actually ask ... a question :)   (they normally end with `?`) eg : "is there a library that will do this for me?"

Comment: freedomn-m got ur point, seems i did miss to ask this as a question, thanks for correcting, have edited that now.
Also, if you notice, the json doesn't have any random change, its only for fixed places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *try* fixing that string by removing quotes that are not key/value delimiters and parse the result as a json:

```js
var text = '["{"a1":"zxcv","a2":"pqrs","c2":[1,2,3],"a3":{"aa3":"asdfgh","aa5":null}}","{"a1":"xyz","a2":"mno","c2":[103],"a3":{"aa8":"qwerty"}}"]';


t = text
    .replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '@$1@:')
    .replace(/:"([^"]+)"/g, ':@$1@')
    .replace(/"/g, '')
    .replace(/@/g, '"')


console.log(JSON.parse(t))
```

If you're interested in what these replacements do exactly, here's a step-by-step visualization:

```js
var text = '["{"a1":"zxcv","a2":"pqrs","c2":[1,2,3],"a3":{"aa3":"asdfgh","aa5":null}}","{"a1":"xyz","a2":"mno","c2":[103],"a3":{"aa8":"qwerty"}}"]';

String.prototype.show = function(s) {
  console.log(s + ": " + this);
  return this;
}


t = text
    .show('Init')
    .replace(/"([^"]+)":/g, '@$1@:')
    .show('Step 1')
    .replace(/:"([^"]+)"/g, ':@$1@')
    .show('Step 2')
    .replace(/"/g, '')
    .show('Step 3')
    .replace(/@/g, '"')
    .show('Step 4')
```

Comment: george, thanks for suggestion, works well, but i'm having a bit of confusion understanding the regex that you have used. Can you explain it a bit?